# C# DataGridView refresh after insert

Tags: c#, datagridview, refresh

I have form A on which is DataGridView and a Button. After clicking a button, new form, form B opens.

On form B i have two textboxes and update button. On clicking that button data is inserted in database. And form B is closed.

How can I update DataGridView to get new data. It's not accesible from form B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShowDialog form B and Return DialogResult After InsertButton Click , Check After From b Call, if DialogResult is Yes Rebind DataGridView (RefreshBindings)

```
//in Form A
private void btnOpenFromB_Click(sender,event)
{
FormB B =new FormB();
if(B.ShowDialog()==DilogResult.Yes)
   //Call RefreshMethod of DG
}


//In Form B
 //in Constructor
public FromB()
{
   initilizeComponents();
   DialogResult=DialogResult.No;
}
//In Insert Button Click
private void InserClick(sender,event)
{
    if(Checking()==true)
     { 
        //Insert Operations
        DialogResult=DilogResult.Yes;
        this.Close();
      }
}
```

Comment: you said that :
"I have form A on which is DataGridView and a Button. After clicking a button, new form, form B opens" , replace your FormB Call with above "FormB B =new FormB(); if(B.ShowDialog()==DilogResult.Yes) //Call RefreshMethod of DGin FormA in FORM A"

Comment: Great Solution, but is there more elegant one ?

Comment: this way is easy and certain, but may be parameter passing to constructor , or using public variables from From A and use that in Form B for determine insert operation. but complicated and high data change risk.

Answer (score 0):

hi Give the Form A in Form B constructor or add it after creating you need to update the grid before closing the Form.

Second way put the data in a field in Form A and than wait the Form B to be closed after closing update the grid.